# Provider org.opensaml.xacml.config.impl.XMLObjectProviderInitializer not a subtype

Tags: java, spring, opensaml

I got this issue these days, when I'm migrating spring-security-saml-extensions-1-x to spring-security-saml2-service-provider which depends on opensaml 3.4.6. At first, I thought it's caused by re-initialize opensaml somehow, from the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/saml2/login/overview.html#servlet-saml2login-opensaml-customization), it says it

> Any class that uses both Spring Security and OpenSAML should statically initialize OpenSamlInitializationService at the beginning of the class.

But no matter I remove the line or not

```
static {
    OpenSamlInitializationService.initialize();
}
```

The issue still happens.
The stackframes like:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:79)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:134)
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:319)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:572)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:419)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.createClass(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:137)
......
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.opensaml.core.config.Initializer: Provider org.opensaml.xacml.config.impl.XMLObjectProviderInitializer not a subtype
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:239)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:185)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:376)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.access$700(ServiceLoader.java:323)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator$2.run(ServiceLoader.java:407)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:409)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
    at org.opensaml.core.config.InitializationService.initialize(InitializationService.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.saml2.core.OpenSamlInitializationService.initialize(OpenSamlInitializationService.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.saml2.core.OpenSamlInitializationService.initialize(OpenSamlInitializationService.java:97)
    at com.mytestsvr.api.config.SecurityConfig.<clinit>(SecurityConfig.java:284)
......
```

I think it's loaded twice since there's a cache item in the stack, but I don't have such opensaml in webapp folder except this one. Any suggestion for resolving such issue?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I googled an answer for this issue on the opensaml forum, http://shibboleth.net/pipermail/dev/2016-July/008417.html
It says:

> Since we know for a fact that
> org.opensaml.core.xml.config.XMLObjectProviderInitializer *is*
> absolutely a subtype of org.opensaml.core.config.Initializer (it's an
> impl of that interface)....

> The only way that I know that this could happen is if you have a very
> strange classloader environment.  This can happen if you have the jars
> living in different classloaders in a hierarchical environment (like a
> servlet container), and/or duplicate jars in the different
> classloaders.  The classloader itself is part of the "identity" of a
> class.  So for example if you have an instance of Foo from classloader
> A, and you do an "foo instanceof Foo" where the class of the latter Foo
> is loaded from classloader B, it will evaluate false.  And the same is
> true for other cases of evaluating an instance's class identity against
> a class literal, etc.

> To avoid all that, do not spread your jars (in this case OpenSAML)
> across multiple classloaders or have duplicate jars in different
> classloaders.  If this is a web app, put all the OpenSAML jars in your
> war, and nowhere else.  Specifically, make sure there are no other
> copies in the servlet container's other classloaders.

And I find that the process which start the tomcat has loaded another opensaml being introduced as the dependency of a framework(but it's actually no use, I think that's why it's hard to find out that in the directory).
After removing this opensaml, it works fine!!!